# Which Fedora package does a specific file belong to?

Tags: fedora, filenames, packaging

In the Debian family of OSes, `dpkg --search /bin/ls` gives:

```
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

That is, the file `/bin/ls` belongs to the Debian package named **coreutils**. (see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-uninstalled-package-a-file-belongs-to) if you are interested in a package containing a file that isn't installed)

What is the Fedora equivalent?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use `rpm -qf /bin/ls` to figure out what package your installed version belongs to:

```
[09:46:58] ~ $ rpm -qf /bin/ls
coreutils-8.5-7.fc14.i686
[09:47:01] ~ $
```

**Update:** Per your comment, the following should work if you want only the name of the package (I just got a chance to test):

```
[01:52:49] ~ $ rpm -qf /bin/ls --queryformat '%{NAME}\n'
coreutils
[01:52:52] ~ $
```

You can also use `dnf provides /bin/ls` to get a list of all available repository packages that will provide the file:

```
# dnf provides /bin/ls
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:06 ago on Tue Jun 27 18:04:08 2017.
coreutils-8.25-17.fc25.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : @System

coreutils-8.25-17.fc25.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : updates

coreutils-8.25-14.fc25.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : fedora
```

Comment: Is there a way to have rpm display owners of a file without providing a full path? You wanna add a note to that effect?

Comment: @Tshepang: I think you should be able to add `--queryformat '%{NAME}'` to accomplish that, but I haven't tested it myself. I can do a quick test and update this after work, though. In the meantime, you might find the info here useful: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html

Comment: Just wanted to add that OpenSuSE's ``zypper`` has a ``what-provides`` feature that accomplishes this task.  This question comes up first when doing a search, so it would be handy to have this answer even though the question is specific.

Comment: For fedora 22 "dnv provides filename" also works

Comment: Please, add a note that for files that are not in the system yet one can use a `dnf provides "*filename"`. I'm sure some people are getting to this post by searching for a way to figure out a package by knowing only a filename *(usually some development headers or libraries)*, and it would be nice if the answer would cover both usecases.