# How do I find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?

Tags: package-management, filenames

On Debian systems (and derivatives):

```
$ dpkg --search /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

That is, the file `/bin/ls` belongs to the Debian package named `coreutils`.

But this only works if the package is installed. What if it's not?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**apt-file**

`apt-file` provides the feature of searching for a package providing a binary (like [Debian](http://packages.debian.org) or [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com)), it is not installed by default but in the repositories.

```
apt-file search <path-to-file>
```

You may want to update once before searching...

```
apt-file update
```

For example, let's search for the not installed binary `mysqldump`:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/mysqldump

mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/mysqldump
mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow
mysql-cluster-client-5.1: /usr/bin/mysqldump
mysql-cluster-client-5.1: /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow
```

It's also possible to list the contents of a (not-installed) package:

```
$ apt-file list mysql-client-5.1

mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/innochecksum
mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/innotop
mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/myisam_ftdump
mysql-client-5.1: /usr/bin/mysql_client_test
...
```

**yum**

`yum` has been largely superseded by `dnf` on modern Fedora/RedHat-based Linux distributions; see below.

`yum` accepts the command `whatprovides` (or `provides`) to search for installed or not installed binaries:

```
yum whatprovides <path-to-file>
```

Again, the not installed `mysqldump`:

```
$ yum whatprovides /usr/bin/mysqldump

mysql-5.1.51-2.fc14.i686 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from: 
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysqldump

mysql-5.1.51-1.fc14.i686 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from: 
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

**dnf**

`dnf` has a `repoquery` subcommand, which you can use similarly to `yum whatprovides`:

```bash
dnf repoquery --whatprovides /path/to/file
```

For example:

```bash
$ dnf repoquery --whatprovides '*/mysqldump'
mariadb-3:10.5.22-1.el9_2.alma.1.x86_64
mysql-0:8.0.36-1.el9_3.x86_64
```

**zypper**

`zypper`'s `search` command can check file lists when used with the `-f` option.

```
zypper se -f /bin/mksh
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name | Summary           | Type   
--+------+-------------------+--------
  | mksh | MirBSD Korn Shell | package
```

[Webpin](http://packages.opensuse-community.org/) provides a webbased solution, there is even a [script](http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2007/07/webpin-command-line-client.html) for the command-line.

**pkgfile**

Available as `pkgtools` for `pacman` based systems. Provides a similar search feature like the others above:

```
$ pkgfile -si /usr/bin/mysqldump

Name      : mysql-clients
Version   : 5.1.54-1
Url       : http://www.mysql.com/
License   : GPL
Depends   : libmysqlclient
...
```

Comment: `apt-file search protoc`, for example, gives over six thousand results. However the results end in the filename, so with grep you can actually find the filename you are looking for: `apt-file search protoc | grep 'protoc$'`. It works because it filters out anything that *ends in* "protoc". Of course you should replace "protoc" with whatever you are searching for.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191983/235261

Comment: yet another option/variant:    `apt-file search -x '/mysqldump$' `

Answer (score 7):

The standard tool for this is **apt-file**. Run `apt-file update` to download the index file. Here's the output:

```
Downloading complete file ftp://ftp.is.co.za/debian/dists/squeeze/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 16.6M  100 16.6M    0     0  33191      0  0:08:47  0:08:47 --:--:-- 38951
```

After that, run `apt-file search search_term`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have access to the machine or can't use the commands given in the previous answers, you can also find this out using the [Debian package web-based search engine](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents) (the second form, "*Search the contents of packages*").

Answer (score 0):

apt-file can produce many results.  With its perl regex, it is almost able to perform the task... if only the file was verified to be installed somewhere in $PATH...

```bash
apt-file find --regexp "/$COMMAND$" | grep -E "($(tr : '|' <<< "$PATH"))/$COMMAND$""
```