# Where is avisplit?

Tags: video, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-package-a-file-belongs-to)

I usually used `avisplit` command to split avi files. I noticed that I should install the package `transcode`.

`$ man transcode`

shows

```
SEE ALSO
       transcode_export(1) , transcode_filter(1) , transcode_import(1) , avifix(1) , avisync(1) , avimerge(1) , avisplit(1) , tcprobe(1) , tcscan(1) ,
       tccat(1) , tcdemux(1) , tcextract(1) , tcdecode(1) , tcmodinfo(1) , tcxmlcheck(1) , transcode(1)
```

though the command `avisplit` does not work.

my OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `$PATH`? What about `type -p avisplit`?

Comment: $PATH is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`. `type -p avisplit` shows nothing.

Comment: The `SEE ALSO` section of a man page is NOT a list of what other programs are in the same package or even a depended upon package.  All it means is the man pages in `SEE ALSO` are related in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/transcode-utils/filelist) says that is should be present in the `transcode-utils` package for your version of ubuntu. However, it seems to be transferred in the `transcode` package for further releases,as [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/km/raring/amd64/transcode/filelist) shows.