# How to fix dpkg-buildpackage: command not found?

Tags: debian, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-package-a-file-belongs-to)

The wish is to install hd-idle on a bare Debian 6.0.6 installation.

For installation the [hd-idle documentation](http://hd-idle.sourceforge.net/) instructs:

> > Run "dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot"

However trying to run that command results in:

```
root@debian:/tmp/hd-idle# dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
-bash: dpkg-buildpackage: command not found
```

How to fix this missing dpkg-buildpackage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to http://packages.debian.org/, go to the bottom of the page (titled *Search the contents of packages*), select your version of Debian, enter `dpkg-buildpackage` as the *keyword* and click *search*. That will tell you which package to install to get the `dpkg-buildpackage` command.

Comment: `dpkg-dev` is the resulting package name.