# Correlating filename with package

Tags: apt, package-management, yum

Say, I'm given a filename like `libasound.so.2`. Is there a way to query the package manager to correlate the filename with its corresponding package?

I'm interested to get answers for any package manager, but my primary focus is on `apt` and `yum`.

Comment: Closely related: [How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6311)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do this for the most common package managers (slightly adapted from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_rosetta)):

1. Debian and its derivatives

   - Installed packages:

     ```
     dpkg -S /path/to/file
     ```

     or

     ```
     dlocate /path/to/file
     ```
   - All available packages

     Install `apt-file` and build its database:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install apt-file && apt-file update
     ```

     Then, search for all packages available in the distribution's repositories (installed or not) that provide the file of interest:

     ```
     apt-file search /path/to/file
     ```
2. Red Hat/Fedora

   - Installed packages:

     ```
     rpm -qf /path/to/file
     ```
   - All available packages:

     ```
     yum whatprovides
     ```
3. SUSE/openSUSE, all other RPM-based distributions

   ```
   rpm -qf /path/to/file
   ```
4. Arch

   ```
   pacman -Qo /path/to/file
   ```
5. Gentoo

   ```
   equery belongs /path/to/file
   ```

Comment: With pacman, the q (quiet) option is also useful: `pacman -Qikk "$(pacman -Qqo /path/to/file)"`

Comment: `urpmf` on mageia

Answer (score 12):

Which installed package provides `/sbin/shutdown` on my system?

```
$ dpkg -S /sbin/shutdown
sysvinit: /sbin/shutdown
```

Which package in the distribution provides `/sbin/shutdown`? Install the [`apt-file`](http://packages.debian.org/apt-file) package and run `apt-file update` if necessary, then

```
$ apt-file search /sbin/shutdown
molly-guard: /usr/sbin/shutdown
sysvinit: /sbin/shutdown
upstart: /sbin/shutdown
```

To download the source (if you're using the default init system SysVinit):

```
apt-get source sysvinit
```

This is probably not the place to configure desktop notifications though. Configuring the boot and shutdown process is typically done through scripts in `/etc/init.d`. Link a script in `/etc/rc0.d` to have it executed on shutdown and in `/etc/rc6.d` to have it executed before rebooting; see the [policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit) for more information. Desktop notifications go through [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. What I meant was to report "System going down in NN minutes" messages that shutdown emits to user terminals via wall command. My initial idea was to make libnotify read wall messages by anyone and display them in desktop. But developers in Debian (Fedora too) felt that best way is for shutdown to call libnotify as they felt writing/reading utmp was archaic.

Comment: One can also use `dlocate` in place of `dpkg -S`.

Answer (score 5):

dpkg -S gives us this on a Ubuntu 10.04

```
dpkg -S /sbin/shutdown 
upstart: /sbin/shutdown
```

But on a Debian 5 box I get this

```
dpkg -S /sbin/shutdown 
sysvinit: /sbin/shutdown
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, this is on a yum based system

```
yum whatprovides /sbin/shutdown
```

or, just use rpm:

```
rpm -qf /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: ..or `rpm -qf $(which shutdown)` to find what package you have installed that is providing that command.

Answer (score 3):

For `apt`, from the manual page for `dpkg`:

```
-S|--search <pattern> ...        Find package(s) owning file(s).
```

You have to give it the full path to the file.

For yum you should be able to query using `rpm`:

```
rpm -qf <path to file>
```

(but I don't have a yum/rpm system to check).

What might be helpful in general (if you know what to do in one or the other package manager):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta