# How to find the package that installed a comand, if "dpkg -S" finds no path because the command is a symlink?

Tags: symlink, dpkg

While I was writing up a tag information for [rename](/questions/tagged/rename), I tried to look up with which package the [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL) command was installed. I ran the usual `dpkg -S` (also mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139356/33055)):

```
$ which rename
/usr/bin/rename
$ dpkg -S $(!!)
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/rename
```

I normally don't install commands by hand in `/usr/bin`, and on the other machines I have access to, `rename` is installed as well. My first suspicion was that this command was copied there in some post-install step of some package.

Then I did an `ls -l /usr/bin/rename` and found that the `rename` command did happen to be a link. I tried `dpkg -S` on the link target (`/etc/alternatives/rename`), but `dpkg -S /etc/alternatives/rename` did not give a package name either.

After some further searching I found that real executable target of that link chain is `/usr/bin/prename` and there is a [bug report for `dpkg -S` behaviour of not following symlinks](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=198220). That report is from 2003 and I could not find any option to follow symlinks for `dpkg` and that issue doesn't seem likely to be resolved.

How can I easily find the package that contains the "real" executable in case the command is a symlink?

Comment: I just want to add that it is definitely **not** a bug that `dpkg -S` doesn't follow symlinks. There are plenty of packages in which a symlink is installed in a different package than the target, with different meanings. `/sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd` is installed by `systemd-sysv`, not `systemd`; `/usr/include/asm` is installed by `gcc-multilib` not whatever arch-specific package, etc.

However, it *does* make sense that symlinks *through* `/etc/alternatives` should be followed.

Comment: @o11c I called it an `issue` on purpose although the original called ig a bug report. A suspect is not necessary a criminal :-). An extra `dpkg` option to follow symlinks would be nice though as that could more easily both show the package that install the symlink (if any) as well as the "real" target. Some more intelligent behaviour around symlinks managed by `update-alternative` would certainly be appropriate, especially as that command is part of the `dpkg` package.

Comment: This is the post-install in question: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/perl/trusty/view/head:/debian/perl.postinst#L16

Answer (score 3):

You can use `readlink` to print where a link points to. The argument to `readlink` without options has to be a link, if you pass it a file, it will not print anything. The `-f` option for `readlink`, from the coreutils package, recursively follows links **and** prints the filename even if the argument already is a file.

If you do (`-n` supresses the newline at the end of the `readlink` output):

```
dpkg -S "$(readlink -fn "$(which rename)")"
```

You will get as answer:

```
perl: /usr/bin/prename
```

that a link was followed is in this case clear from the `prename`, but this is not guaranteed to be the case (e.g. if a link was pointing to an executable `rename` in a directory that is not in your $PATH).

As @011c indicated, and if you have it installed, you can use `realpath` as alternative to `readlink -f`

Comment: Better to use `realpath` than `readlink -f`, since not all versions of `readlink` support the `-f` flag, but `realpath` is going to DTRT if it exists.

Comment: @o11c Are there other version of readlink than the coreutils version? Or are you talking about old implementations (how old)?

Comment: It's not specified by POSIX, and OSX and *BSD versions don't support it, or make it mean something completely different.

Comment: You don't need `-n`: `$()` already eats up trailing newlines.