# Find the service from an installed package (rpm)

Tags: bash, rpm, services, ansible

I'm trying to link a list of installed packages to the services they have running on a system (init.d).
I'm using ansible for this, but of course a bash hint is also usable.

For example if upon examination it turns out that openssh is installed, I want that the state and status of the service sshd is also reported.

Which ways are there to find out which services belong to which package ?

Comment: `rpm -qf` on the running binary?

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139356/117549

Comment: How should Ansible know that openssh package provides the system with ssh service? Are you looking for "brute-force" searching installed packages for /etc/init.d/* and testing it?

Comment: Hey Jeff, please convert your comment to an answer to give you the credit for the solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can play with something like:

```
rpm -qal |grep /usr/lib/systemd/system/ |xargs -l1 basename | xargs systemctl status
```

> Which ways are there to find out which services belong to which package ?

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/systemd/system/podman.service
```