# How can I find the package that contains a program in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am using a minimal Debian system which does not have the `top` program installed. I tried to install top with `sudo apt-get install top`, but `top` is not a package name.

It seems that `top` is a part of some other package. How can I find out which package I should install to get it? More generally, how can I find the package that contains a program?

Comment: On a well-bloated Ubuntu system, running eg. `laps` when it isn't installed triggers the message "The program 'laps' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install epix`". Can you add that functionality to your system?

Comment: It's not thru apt, but there is a simple web interface that allows you to search for packages: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257905/how-can-i-tell-which-package-an-executable-came-from

Comment: You can regex search the description of all the packages. It can also be helpful in other contexts than just finding a certain executable.

In the following example the command `dig` is being searched for
`apt show '*' | grep --regexp '[^A-Za-z]dig[^A-Za-z]' --before-context 30 --after-context 5 --color=always  | less --raw-control-chars`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The direct answer is `procps`. Here is how you can find this out for yourself:

```
# Install apt-file, which allows you to search
# for the package containing a file
sudo apt-get install apt-file

# Update the package/file mapping database
sudo apt-file update

# Search for "top" at the end of a path
apt-file search --regexp '/top$'
```

The output of the final command should look something like this:

```
crossfire-maps: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
crossfire-maps-small: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
liece: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/liece/styles/top
lxpanel: /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/two_panels/panels/top
procps: /usr/bin/top
quilt: /usr/share/quilt/top
```

You can see that only `procps` provides an executable in your standard PATH, which gives a clue that it might be the right one. You can also find out more about `procps` to make sure like it seems like the right one:

```
$ apt-cache show procps
Package: procps
Version: 1:3.3.3-3

[...]

Description-en: /proc file system utilities
 This package provides command line and full screen utilities for browsing
 procfs, a "pseudo" file system dynamically generated by the kernel to
 provide information about the status of entries in its process table
 (such as whether the process is running, stopped, or a "zombie").
 .
 It contains free, kill, pkill, pgrep, pmap, ps, pwdx, skill, slabtop,
 snice, sysctl, tload, top, uptime, vmstat, w, and watch.
```

Comment: I like this answer way more than the post the mods linked to. Without `--regexp` the search goes bananas with the results, as in +10000 results when searching for shortnamed commands, such as **dig**.

Comment: I totally forgot about apt-file search - super helpful thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You can search for things with `apt-cache search ...`, although it is just a match on package names and descriptions, which sometimes is not enough.  In that case using, e.g.,

```
apt-file search top
```

might work -- it finds all packages that have a file with `top` in their name, but for this that is a bit zany (it includes `setopt`, `.desktop`, etc).  To refine this as per Chris's answer:

```
apt-file search --regexp 'bin/top$'
```

This will find packages that have a file path ending ('$' is [**reg**ular **exp**ression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax signifying the end) in `bin/top`; executables are always in either a `bin` or `sbin` directory.  When you find what you're looking for:

`apt-get install whatever`

In this case `whatever` is apparently `procps`.

Comment: By default, `apt-file search` takes a literal substring pattern to search for, not a glob. At least on my system, `apt-file search "*/top"` returns 0 results.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yeah.  I changed this to use `--regexp` and added an explanation that's absent from your otherwise very complete answer ;)

Comment: It's `yum provides ...` that works with file globs.

Comment: Whoever drive-by downvoted this answer and mine at the same time, I'm sure both me and goldilocks would appreciate some feedback instead of just blind downvoting :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown I'm guessing a "just give me the codes, I don't want any explanations" attitude.

Answer (score 3):

apt-file search all repos listed in /etc/apt/sources.list and related databases, as long as repo serve a contents-%architecture%.gz.

if believe the file of interest is an executable name "top", use this regex. '^/(usr/)?s?bin/top$'

for the official debian repo, there is a web interface https://packages.debian.org/file:top, there are other search options.