# Get name of package containing a given binary

Tags: apt, package-management

Given the name of a binary (or any other program). How to find out which package provides this binary?

*Note:* Assuming one uses `apt`/`dpkg` for package managing.

**Edit**

Additional to the correct answer below, I'd like to add some further information: In the question above I was assuming that *the corresponding package was installed*. If this is **not** the case, there is a package called `apt-file` which could do the job anyway.

Searching for the `mysqldump` tool could be done with

```
$ apt-file --regexp search .*mysqldump$
```

Resulting in:

```
mariadb-client-10.0: /usr/bin/mysqldump
mysql-client-5.5: /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

This solution was found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6314/93225) but I thought it could be of use to mention it here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want [dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html). Specifically the `-S` option will find which package owns a file.

An example:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/whereis
util-linux: /usr/bin/whereis
```

The example shows that `util-linux` is the package which contains `/usr/bin/whereis`.

Comment: also [How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-package-a-file-belongs-to)

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg --search /usr/bin/mysqldump
dpkg -S /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

The argument of `dpkg --search` is a shell wildcard pattern, so you can do things like `dpkg -S bin/*dump`.

Alternatively, you can search the database manually — it's just text files.

```
grep mysqldump /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
```

On a system with a lot of packages installed, `dpkg -S` can be slow because it has to read a lot of small files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. You can install [dlocate](https://packages.debian.org/dlocate) which indexes files installed via deb packages in the same way that `locate` indexes all files: the information is a bit stale (by default, the database is updated nightly) but the query operation is faster.