# How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to on NixOS?

Tags: package-management, nixos, nix

I am using a [Nix package manager](https://nixos.org/nix/) on [NixOS](http://nixos.org/). Suppose I want to install a package that provides a file `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`. How do I find a package that provides this file, similar to [other GNU/Linux distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6311/11397)?

Currently I have to google the file and figure out which package it might belong and find the corresponding package on Nix repository, but I would like a more idiomatic method.

Comment: I got as far as "setup a ctags database..." https://nixos.org/wiki/Howto_find_a_package_in_NixOS#Indexing_and_searching_Nix_files before giving up.

Comment: Some package managers (e.g. `yum` and `dnf` in RPMland) allow you to say "install file", they figure out the right package and install that one.

Comment: We only have this for executables ATM (`$ command-not-found foo`). Note that searching nix files (e.g. with ctags) won't help there. You do have to perform the build to find what it installs.

Comment: Why? Are other package managers really have such a function? More "idiomatic" method is to read `INSTALL` file of the package (for which you want to create the environment), namely the `Requirements`/`Dependencies` section for the packages you have to have pre-installed. Then look for the *packages* in `nixpkgs`. (In other words, package managers are about packages not files...)

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky, because sometimes you know the name of a command (or another filename) but not the name of the package that provides it. And yes, other package managers have such a feature, e.g. `yum provides '*/bin/grep'` or `dnf provides '*/bin/grep` or `apt-file search 'fprintf.3.gz'`.

Answer (score 28):

[nix-index](https://github.com/bennofs/nix-index) is what you need.

Install and build the index:

```
nix-env -iA nixos.nix-index
nix-index
```

Locate `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`:

```
nix-locate -w libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

Output:

```
(zed.out)                                             0 s /nix/store/bc4mngklj2j7hmm21jra4641x4pm9r8z-node-webkit-env/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
(thrust.out)                                          0 s /nix/store/wzg0k4i2cy0qsm3hwxlywxxbga019hbq-env-thrust/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
(nwjs_0_12.out)                                       0 s /nix/store/js6klvzjfi5q4djmwb0bqzfb4x0vzm6g-nwjs-env/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
(node_webkit_0_11.out)                                0 s /nix/store/30vm6a7bmc56ckl575rqassw60ccxjpg-node-webkit-env/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
(mumble_overlay.out)                                  0 s /nix/store/wayx023w1nslqg2z0c5v4n0b4jxn5n06-gtk+-2.24.31/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
gnome2.gtk.out                                        0 s /nix/store/3iqchhncghm5s458lzy99c3prfymrnp2-gtk+-2.24.31/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

The last line says that package `gtk+-2.24.31` with attribute path `gnome2.gtk` contains this file.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the documentation it doesn't look like there is an easy way to do this.

With yum based distro you could do `yum provides $file` and in apt-get distro you could install apt-file and do `apt-file $file` but I cannot see an equivalent in `nix-env -q`.