# Searching a keyword in man

Tags: linux, man

I am trying to search for keyword in manual pages, but it doesn't work here.

```
$ man -k syslog
Syslog: nothing appropriate.
```

Comment: Not sure what distro you are using, but its possible the man packages aren't installed. Here is some discussion about that on CentOS: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252530/how-to-install-man-pages-on-centos

Comment: I Am using linux

Comment: @Abhishekmehra Linux isn't a [distro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

After installing new packages, their documentation (man pages) are installed but not yet loaded into the man pages search database. So, you should run

```
mandb
```

to generate or refresh the search database for manpage entries.