# Remove a software on Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt

I would like to remove the Network manager's binary on Debian 9. This software is called nm-applet. nm-applet is contained in the PATH. However if I try to remove this software, it is not found. In order to remove the software I use the following command:

```
sudo apt remove nm-applet
```

The package is not found is displayed as an output of the run command. Does anybody know why the package is not found if executing the above named command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out which (not installed) Debian package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-debian-package-a-file-belongs-to) Note "not installed" in this case means "not necessarily installed".

Comment: Plus the question itself gives you `dpkg --search …`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am not searching for a solution on how to find for the binary. Instead I am wondering why the binary cannot be removed if the "sudo apt remove nm-applet" is run. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Because the `nm-applet` *binary* is not from `nm-applet` *package*. There is no such package. Run `dpkg --search /usr/bin/nm-applet` or `apt-file search bin/nm-applet` and find the *right* package.