# mkfs.vfat -- No such file or directory

Tags: debian, mkfs, vfat

I'm on Debian Bookworm.

I am trying to format my USB drive to FAT32 filesystem.

```
~$ lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                                                                         
└─sdb1
     ntfs         SONY  2DE23E532C9D2CAC
```

When I tried `mkfs` I get the following error:

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for vrgovinda: 
mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.vfat: No such file or directory
```

I have the following installed:

```
exfatprogs
udisks2
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mkfs.vfat` is in [`dosfstools`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mkfs.vfat&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)

Comment: I upvoted your comment since it was right. But in the link that you have provided, `apt-file search <path-to-binary>`, I get an error that `apt-file: command not found`

Comment: That answer clearly states "it is not installed by default but in the repositories", the package index I used is mentioned in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13744/70524)

Comment: Thank you. How can I get `apt-file`; There's nothing like that in my repositories. I use Debian Bookworm

Comment: It definitely is packaged for Bookworm: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/apt-file

Comment: oh yes! I'm really sorry. `apt-file search mkfs.vfat
dosfstools: /sbin/mkfs.vfat               
dosfstools: /usr/share/man/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.gz
fish-common: /usr/share/fish/completions/mkfs.vfat.fish
manpages-de: /usr/share/man/de/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.gz
manpages-fr: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.gz
manpages-pl: /usr/share/man/pl/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.gz`

Comment: I've installed `dosfstools` and my work is done! Thank you muru!